# Meaning of "I was mad that one year" in a birthday message by Will Smith

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, demonstrative, demonstrative-pronouns

I have just read a great *[post](https://www.facebook.com/WillSmith/photos/a.10150451669175161.638119.92304305160/10155950973550161/?type=1)* by Will Smith containing that sentence (I was mad that one year) but I do not understand its meaning. Is "That One" similar to "that first"?

> This was taken at your mom's house 20 years ago. That's a long time ago!!! So I decided to do some math...
>
> I have sung happy birthday to you 20 times and I have bought you 19 birthday presents (**I was mad that one year**). I have watched you blow out 693 candles (737 after tonite). I've told you "I love you" at least 8,285 times. And of the nearly 3.96 Billion women on the planet - there is only 1 that I want to spend the rest of my life with.
>
> Happy Birthday, my Love!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That one year" could be used to refer to any year, not just the first year of something.  This sentence out of context does not contain enough information to know which year in particular Will Smith is talking about.  [Edit:  I have looked into the post in question.  The sentence is "I have sung happy birthday to you 20 times and I have bought you 19 birthday presents (I was mad that one year)..."  The meaning of the phrase in this context is that Will Smith was mad at his wife on the particular year, so he didn't get her a birthday present.]

Comment: Ok! Here there is the post: "I have sung happy birthday to you 20 times and I have bought you 19 birthday presents (I was mad that one year)...[...]"

Comment: @superciccio14 I looked it up moments before you commented haha my answer is updated with the meaning

Comment: Thanks! So "that one year" is like "that year"! Is "One" a kind of intensifier?